# Regex with non-capturing hashbangs

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex which will parse the hash portion of a URL, removing whichever conventionally-formatted hashbang may be present.

For example, I wish to remove any of the following:

```
#
#/
#!
#!/
```

This is what I currently have:

```
/[(?:#|#\/|#!|#!\/)]+/
```

However, this is capturing an empty group at the start, and splitting the remaining strings. For example,

```
"#!/E/F".split(/[(?:#|#\/|#!|#!\/)]/);    //  ["", "", "", "E", "F"]
```

Whereas the desirable outcome is simply a single group

```
["E/F"]
```

Could someone please point out the error in my regex?

[*If it makes a difference, I produced the above output using the JavaScript console in Firebug.*]

Comment: Your capturing group is invoking the little-known behavior of `split` where it include the splitting elements in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.replace` instead of `string.split`.

```
#!?\/?
```

Use the above regex and then replace the match with empty string.

```
> '#!/E/F'.replace(/#!?\/?/g, '');
'E/F'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hL2lE6/12)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems awfully complicated. Maybe this is more what you're looking for:
"#!/E/F".split(/(#!/|#/|#!|#)/);

Did you checkout the [Javascript regex documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)?

It might be different from what you imagined, since I don't understand why you're using the : and ? in your regex.

Comment: Sorry, the `:` and `?` ahouldn't have been there - I copy-pasted from a work-in-progress. They weren't present in the example with the actionable string. I've since edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Javascript then you can just use:

```
location.assign(location.href.replace(/#.*$/, ""));
```

However if you only want to remove above listed hashtags then use:

```
var repl = location.href.replace(/#(!\/?|\/)?$/, '');
```